# What is the expectation value ${\Bbb E}[\langle\psi,O\psi\rangle]$ over the Haar distribution?

Tags: haar-distribution

What is the average $\mathbb{E}_{\text{Haar}}|\langle\psi|O\psi\rangle|$ of expectation of an arbitrary observable $O$ over the Haar distribution? Let $d$ be the dimension, i.e, the size of $O$. Do we have something similar to $$\mathbb{E}_{\text{Haar}}\langle\psi|O\psi\rangle=\frac{\text{tr}O}{d}?$$

Comment: Certainly not the trace, since the lhs has to be positive.

Comment: You’re right. I edited my question.

Comment: Yes, you can check eq.(11) in this paper https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-07090-4.pdf .

Comment: That's an entirely different - and *much* easier - question!

Answer (score 7):

Since a Haar-random $\lvert\psi\rangle=U\lvert0\rangle$ for a Haar-random $U$, your expectation value equals
$$
\langle 0 \rvert \Big[\int \mathrm d U\, UOU^\dagger\Big]\lvert0\rangle\ .
$$
The integral in the brackets must be proportional to the identity matrix (that's Schur's lemma -- the identity is the only operator which commutes with all unitaries), and the proportionality constant can easily be determined to be $\mathrm{tr}(O)/\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{Id})=\mathrm{tr}(O)/d$.

Thus,
$$
\langle 0 \rvert \Big[\int \mathrm d U\, UOU^\dagger\Big]\lvert0\rangle
= 
\langle 0 \rvert \frac{\mathrm{tr}(O)}{d} \mathrm{Id} \lvert0\rangle
= \frac{\mathrm{tr}(O)}{d}\ ,
$$
as you indeed suspected.

Comment: I know about Schur's Lemma but I fail to see why should the integral commute with all unitaries, is there some simple argument for that that I'm missing?

Comment: Basically Schur's Lemma says that $I$ is the only matrix which transforms trivially under $X\mapsto UXU^\dagger$. And everything which transforms non-trivially will averge out to zero.