# What is the expectation value of the overlap of two uniformly random pure states?

Tags: quantum-state, fidelity, haar-distribution

Let $\psi$ and $\phi$ be two uniformly random pure state $\psi, \phi \sim\mathbb{C}^d$. The the following equality holds
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{\psi, \phi \sim \mathbb{C}^d} {\rm Tr}[\vert \phi \rangle \phi \vert \psi \rangle \langle \psi \vert] = \mathbb{E}_{\psi, \phi \sim \mathbb{C}^d} \vert \langle \phi \vert\psi \rangle\vert^2 = \frac{1}{d} \tag{1}.
\end{align}
How to prove Eq. (1)?

Comment: possible duplicate of one of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/28615/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/25883/55,  or https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/28707/55 (observing that by symmetry the question is equivalent to fixing one of the states and only averaging wrt the other one)

Comment: Thank you gIS.  The Eq. (1) can be obtained using the properties of Haar measure from the above link.